# jq syntax help for querying lists output

Tags: jq

I need help in correcting jq test cases syntax. Following is output file & trying to test ID list with command below. Gives error index to string type.

```
[[ $(echo $output| jq -r '.output.value[] | select(.identity).id_list') == *"id2"*  ]]

output = {
   "resource_output": {

    "value": {
           "identity": [
            {
              "id_list": [
                "/subscriptions/---/id1",
                "/subscriptions/---/id2",
                "/subscriptions/--/id3"
             ],
             "principal_id": "",
             "tenant_id": "",
             "type": "managed"
           }
         ]
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not match the sample JSON, and you have not indicated what output you are expecting, but the following variation of your query illustrates how to use `select` and `test` with your data along the lines suggested by your attempt:

```
echo "$output" |
  jq -r '.resource_output.identity[].id_list[] | select(test("id2"))'
```

Output:

```
/subscriptions/---/id2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated output file in which properties are included in values block & tried below bash but it gives error.
echo "$output" |
  jq -r '.resource_output.value[].identity[].id_list[] | select(test("id2"))'